# How to Set quantity of Product in each bundle?

Tags: custom-object, standard-objects, configuration, product, cpq

we have a Custom object Bundle__c and in this object i have a related list of Product (Product2 is standard Object)

Now, if i add quantity field in this related list then quantity of this product is associate 
with that perticular bundle.. but my concern is if i add quantity to perticular product then it is set as a global
but what i need is how can i add seprate quantity to each product in perticular bundle ?

for example : Pr1 is product and B1 & B2 are Bundle

B1 has Pr1 in related list and it has quantity is 2

B2 has same product Pr1 in related list and it has quantity is 4

How can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Junction Object` here between Bundle and product. Because one product might related to many Bundles.

So use a junction and create a `quantity` field and store the quantity there. Using this you will get different quantity for Each Bundle and Product set.

Comment: In this case i am going to create Junction object named : `Product quantity` and this object need to have two lookup fields for `Bundle__c` & `Product`, correct me if i am wrong.. :)

Comment: @HSdev yes you are correct.

Comment: One more question please, How can i display it(Quantity) in related list of Product ? do i need apex code for the same or something else ?

Comment: @HSdev no apex needed . You can just add the field in related list.

Comment: Ok. now, i got the exact word :) i need to add this Product Quantity as a related list under Bundle object....right ?

Comment: @HSdev yes in your junction object create quantity field and add it in layout.